# Project Euler 50: Algorithm is incredibly slow, failing to understand why

Tags: haskell, primes

I'm using Project Euler to learn Haskell. I'm new at Haskell and am having a lot of trouble coming up with an algorithm that doesn't take an absurd amount of time. I'm estimating that the program here would take 14 gigayears to arrive at the solution.

The problem:

> Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most
>   consecutive primes?

Here's my source. I've left out isPrime. I've posted it because it's far too inefficient to solve the problem. I think the issue lies with the slicedChains and primeChains calls, but I'm not sure what it is. I've resolved this before with C++. But for whatever reason, the efficient solution seems beyond me in Haskell.

Edit: I've included isPrime.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.List (nub,maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime x
        | any (== 0) (fmap (x `mod`) [2..x-1]) = False
        | otherwise = True

primeChain :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeChain x = [ n | n <- 1 : 2 : [3,5..x-1], isPrime n ]

slice :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]
slice xs args = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)
    where from = head args
          to = last args

subsequencesOfSize :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subsequencesOfSize n xs = let l = length xs
                          in if n>l then [] else subsequencesBySize xs !! (l-n)
    where
        subsequencesBySize [] = [[[]]]
        subsequencesBySize (x:xs) = let next = subsequencesBySize xs
                                    in zipWith (++) ([]:next) (map (map (x:)) next ++ [[]])

slicedChains :: Int -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
slicedChains len xs = nub [x | x <- fmap (xs `slice`) subseqs, length x > 1]
    where subseqs = [x | x <- (subsequencesOfSize 2 [1..len]), (last x) > (head x)]

primeSums :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
primeSums x = filter (\ns -> sum ns == x) chain
    where xs = primeChain x
          len = length xs
          chain = slicedChains len xs

compLength :: [[a]] -> [a]
compLength xs = maximumBy (comparing length) xs

cleanSums :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
cleanSums xs = fmap (compLength) filtered
    where filtered = filter (not . null) (fmap primeSums xs)

main :: IO()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let arg = read (head args) :: Integer
    let xs = primeChain arg
    print $ maximumBy (comparing length) $ cleanSums xs
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling on a smaller input size (primes below 1000 for example) and seeing which function is taking the most time?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's slicedChains and maybe the double call of primeChain. I'm just not entirely sure how to avoid them.

Comment: You probably want to use a sieve to make a vector (or even a list) of all the primes up to a million and then you probably want to shove those into an `IntSet`. The vector of primes will let you sum up consecutive ones really easily, while the `IntSet` will make it easy to check if a number is prime.

Comment: a suboptimal `isPrime` could easily be a culprit. why should it be left out? it shouldn't.

Comment: I've included my isPrime function. It seems that it runs in linear time if I'm calculating it correctly.

Comment: you where right, it almost doesn't matter, though your code is very slow, *quadratic* (not linear by a long shot); yet even with it the solution can be found in few seconds (NB @dfeuer re: sieve -- normal TD is more than adequate here, it turns out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are not pruning your search space based on the best solution you have found so far.

I can tell this just from the fact that you are using `maximumBy` to find the longest sequence.

For instance, if during your search your find a consecutive sequence of 4 primes whose sum is a prime < 10^6, you don't have to examine any sequence which begins with a prime greater than 250000.

To do this kind of pruning you have to keep track of the solution found so far and interleave the testing of candidate sequences with their generation so that the best solution found so far can stop the search early.

**Update**

There are several inefficiencies in `slicedChains`. Haskell lists are implemented a linked lists. This video is pretty good overview of linked lists and how they differ from arrays: [(link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBrz9HmjFOs)

The following expressions in your code are going to be problematic w.r.t. efficiency:

***** `nub` has quadratic running time

***** `length x > 1` - the complexity of `length` is O(n) where n is the length of the list. A better way to write this is:

```
lengthGreaterThan1 :: [a] -> Bool
lengthGreaterThan1 (_:_:_) = True
lengthGreaterThan1 _       = False
```

***** `subsequencesOfSize 2 [1..len]` may be more succinctly written:

```
[ [a,b] | a <- [1..len], b <- [a+1..len] ]
```

and this will also ensure that a < b.

***** The `take` and `drop` calls in `slice` are also O(n)

***** In `primeSums` the call to `primeChain` will regenerate essentially the same list over and over again resulting in a lot of multiple calls to `isPrime`. A better approach is to define `primeChain` like this:

```
allPrimes = filter isPrime [1..]

primeChain x = takeWhile (<= x) allPrimes
```

The list `allPrimes` will be generated once, and `primeChain` simply takes prefixes of that list.

***** `primeSums x` is charged with finding sequences whose sum is *exactly* x, but it looks at a lot of sequences that can't possibly work. For instance, `primeSums 31` will examine:

```
11 + 13 + 17, 11 + 13 + 17 + 23, 11 + 13 + 17 + 23 + 29,
17 + 19, 17 + 19 + 23, 17 + 19 + 23 + 29,
19 + 23, 19 + 23 + 29
23 + 29
```

even though it's pretty obvious that none of these sums could equal 31.

Comment: Thanks. What sort of structure or function would I be using to do the interleaving and tracking? I assume it'd be some kind of map.

Answer (score 2):

So the first thing you need is a good data structure: Once you find a sequence of length `n` you don't care about sequences of shorter length, so your primary needs are: (1) tracking the sum, (2) tracking the primes in the set, (3) removing the least element, (4) adding a new greatest element. The key is **amortization**, where a big cost is paid infrequently enough that you can pretend it is a small cost per procedure. The data structure looks like this:

```
data Queue x = Q [x] [x]
q_empty (Q [] []) = True
q_empty _ = False

q_headtails (Q (x:xs) rest) = (x, Q xs rest)
q_headtails (Q [] xs) = case reverse xs of y:ys -> (y, Q ys [])
                                           []   -> error "End of queue."

q_append el (Q beg end) = Q beg (el:end)
```

So deconstructing the list is possible, but sometimes triggers an O(n) operation, but that's OK because when it does, we won't have to do it for another `n` steps, so it averages out to one operation per step. (You might also want to do it with a spine-strict list.)

To save on length operations and summing the items of the list you probably want to cache those, too:

```
type Length = Int
type Sum = Int
type Prime = Int
data PrimeSeq = PS Length Sum (Queue Prime)

headTails (PS len sum q) = (x, PS (len - 1) (sum - x) xs)
  where (x, xs) = q_headtails q

append x (PS len sum xs) = PS (len + 1) (sum + x) (q_append x xs)
```

The algorithm for these looks like:

1. Cache a copy of the PrimeSeq you're starting with
2. Keep adding primes to it and testing primality until you get to 10^6.
3. If you find a new prime with a longer sequence, replace the cache.
4. Whenever you run into 10^6, revert to the cache, pull a prime off the front of the queue, then repeat as needed.

Comment: turns out, lists are fast enough here; though I couldn't include the code in my answer because that's PE after all.

Answer (score 2):

Your prime generation is quadratic (`isPrime 101` tests `rem 101 100 == 0` even though *10* is the biggest number by which *101* needs to be tested -- and actually *7* is enough).

Yet even with it, a simple enough ***list-based*** code finds the answer in under *2* seconds (on an Intel Core i7 2.5 GHz, ***interpreted*** in GHCi). And with the code corrected to take advantage of the above mentioned optimization (and additionally, testing by primes only), it takes *0.1s*.

Also, `f x | t = False | otherwise = True` is the same as `f x = not t`.

We are asked by the PE site not to give you even a hint.

But in general, the key to efficiency in Haskell, thanks to its laziness, is being ***generative*** with as small a duplication of effort as possible. As one example, instead of calculating each slice of a list in isolation starting anew, we can produce the bunch of them together as part of one process,

```
 slices :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
 slices n = map (take n) . iterate tail -- sequence of list's slices of length n each
```

Another principle is, try to solve a more ***general*** problem, of which yours is an instance.

Having written such a function, we can play with it by trying out different values for its parameters, from smaller to the bigger ones, for an exploratory style of problem solving. We're told about *21* consecutive primes. What about *22* of them? *27*? *1127* of them? ... and I've said enough about this already.

If it starts taking too much time, we can assess the full solution's needed run time by [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) analysis.

Though the solution is found quickly enough with your unoptimized `isPrime` code, the exploratory process can be prohibitively slow with it, but it is fast enough with the optimized code:

```
 primes :: [Int]
 primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]
 isPrime n = and [rem n p > 0 | p <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) primes]
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. What's the difference between rem and mod?

Comment: @thespectre if both arguments are positive, there's no difference. but `rem` sometimes is faster.